# Sitefinity module install failure

Tags: sitefinity

I created a new module by following the testimonials example in the SDK. But, it won't install. There are no error messages to help direct me in a certain direction.

I've fired up the project in debug mode setting a break point on the install method, but it never gits hit.

Anyone know why that would be?

Thanks,
Jacques

Answer (score 1):

If it's not installing it might not be properly registered in the system. What version of Sitefinity is this? If one of the more recent ones there is a section under Administration > Modules where you can install the module. Otherwise you need to do it in the Administration > Settings > Advanced > System > Application Modules and create a new entry there manually

Either way, make sure that the full name of your module is correct (including the namespace) as the Type, and that the startupType is set to "OnApplicationStart" so it initializes when the website starts.

Then force your website to restart (easiest way is to just save the web.config file) and it should fire up.

I hope this is helpful!

If you have done all this and it's still not firing, can you tell me if the module is listed in the systemConfig.Config file under app_data folder?

Comment: Hi @Josh. I've confirmed all the above (namespaces and so forth) and they're correct. In fact just to do some troubleshooting, I installed Sitefinity 5.1, installed Thunder, created a new folder under Modules, added a new Sitefinity Custom Module item using Thunder (which added the two classes as well as the entry in the SystemConfig.config file). I then made a change to the web.config to force the restart... and nothing. The module is listed under Administration > Modules and even if I click Actions > Install, it does nothing.

Comment: is your module listed in systemConfig.config? If so, is there a value for "Version"? If there is, delete this value so it reads Version="", then save web.config and start the website again. this should force the module to reinstall. hope this helps!

Comment: Hi @Josh, yes it's listed in the SystemConfig.config, but it has no version. ?

Comment: is it possible for you to share this project so I can take a closer look? if not, I would suggest opening a ticket with support so you can share it privately with them, as they can take a closer look and see why it's not installing...

Comment: Hi @Josh, I can share the project yes. Thing is... even if I use Thunder and create a new dummy module, it doesn't install either. Is there any reason all of this could be caused by the fact that I'm working with the Community Edition?

Comment: i'm not aware of any restrictions in the CE that would prevent a module from being installed. if you can zip the project and database and send me a link to josh.morales @telerik .com I'll take a look!

Comment: Last night, I reinstalled Thunder and tried this on a Professional edition project and low and behold Thunder creates many more files than before. This is a great step in the right direction, but still it won't install the module. It's listed in the SystemConfig.config file, but won't install.